# $S^1 \times S^1$ is homeomorphic to torus

Tags: general-topology, geometry

The question is asking to show $S^1 \times S^1$ is homeomorphic to a torus. I have read some other posts in here but most of them are proving it with "lattice" which I haven't learn. Here is what I did, write down a function $f: T/\sim \text{}\rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$

where $T= [0,1] \times [0,1]/\sim$ whit relation $(0,a)\sim(1,a)$, $(b,0)\sim(b,1)$ for $a,b \in [0,1]$

and

$$f(x,y)=(\cos(2\pi x),\sin(2\pi x),\cos(2\pi y),\sin(2\pi y))$$

And I wish to show that $f$ is a homeomorphism. (Recall from lecture, I need to show $f$ is a continuous bijection with continuous inverse $f^{-1}$.)

How do I show $f$ is a bijection and what is $f^{-1}$? Is that $f^{-1}(x,u,y,v)=(\mid \frac{1}{2\pi}\arccos(x)\mid,\mid \frac{1}{2\pi}\arccos(y)\mid)$

Comment: The problem is that $\arccos$ picks a single value of amulti-valued function. In particular, it never picks a value in $[\pi,2\pi]$.

Comment: Far better, therefore, is to use "atan2", a slight generalization of arctan: for $x > 0$, $atan2(x, y) = arctan(y/x)$, and for other quadrants, it differs from $arctan(y/x)$ by a constant. It's discontinuous on the non-positive $x$ axis. You can recover $x$ from $(p,q,r,s)$ by $x = atan2(q, p)$, and simmilarly $y = atan2(s, r)$.

Comment: Note that since the torus is compact and $S^1 \times S^1$ is Hausdorf, you actually only need to show that $f$ is a continuous bijection; the rest is [automatic](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism).

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I probably wouldn't use the Cartesian coordinates for $S^1$, but a polar coordinate,

$$f(x,y) = (2\pi x, 2\pi y)  \mod 2\pi$$

Then the inverse is slightly easier, $f^{-1}(\alpha, \beta) = (\alpha/2\pi, \beta/2\pi)$

Comment: isn't $f(x,y)=(1,2\pi x,1,2\pi y)$, since $f:T/\sim$ $\to S^1 \times S^1$.

Comment: I don't understand the $1$ and the image having three ordinates. My thinking is that $S^1 \times S^1$ has two ordinates.

Comment: $S^1 \times S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^4$, so I expect the image has 4 components. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Six of one, half a dozen of another. If you have a definition of $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ without other homeomorphic representations, stick with it. If that is the case, my solution is perhaps a bit of a 'cheat' as it de facto uses $[0, 1]/\sim  \ \cong S^1$.